# Linear independence of $x, x^3, |x^3|$

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I make sure whether $x, x^3, |x^3|$ are linearly independent? I know I have to show that $$kx+lx^3+m|x^3|=0\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad \Rightarrow k=l=m=0,$$ but I'm not sure how to do this. Should I plug in different values for $x$?

Comment: You should show that there doesnt exist any $k,l,m$ such that $kx+lx^3+m|x^3|=0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\{0},$ to show they are independent

Comment: On the contrary: You have to show that $kx+lx^3+m|x^3|=0$ for all $x$ cannot happen for any choice of $k,l,m$.

Comment: So assume that such $k,l,m$ exist. Substitute some values of $x$ to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the idea is good! For $x=1$ you get
$$
k+l+m=0
$$
For $x=-1$ you get
$$
-k-l+m=0
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: @user391135 From these you get $m=0$, and $l=-k$. Now try $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: if they were dependent, $|x|^3$ was a polynomial as a linear combination of $x$ and $x^3$. This is of course impossible.